# spring integration poller ignoring day light saving

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have job which polls files from 5pm in the evening to 5 AM next day morning. We process files delivered during this period only and what ever left would be processed in next window.

But recently we noticed that we processed files even after 5AM in the morning until 6AM. Now our cron expression(0/30 * 0-5,17-23 * * *) is configured such a way that it should have stopped at 5AM but it did not stopped until 6AM.

This means it has ignored the day light saving and continued until 6AM

Is there anyone who has faced this problem before? Or know what should be the fix.

I checked the code for CronTrigger.java but could not find anything other than time zone.

I also checked time zone setup in our linux box and it is EDT.

Wed Apr  6 10:59:47 EDT 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CronTrigger` is a part of Spring Framework, not Spring Integration. That's minor, of course.

The `CronTrigger` algorithm is based on the [CronTab](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) (`CronSequenceGenerator`), which doesn't support `daylight shifts` (see in the end of that article):

> If you are in one of the 70-odd countries that observe Daylight Savings
>        Time, jobs scheduled during the rollback or advance will be affected.  In
>        general, it is not a good idea to schedule jobs during this period.

Looks like Quartz [support](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-240) that for awhile already, but we don't support Quartz [pollers](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2731) yet. Although you can hook the Spring Integration flow from the Quartz Job similar to the `<poller>`.

From other side, please, raise a ticket for the Spring Framework (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR) to consider to add daylight saving to the `CronTrigger`.